# Yard doc and `define_method`

Tags: ruby, documentation, yard

Is there a way to comment methods defined with `define_method` in [YardDoc](http://yardoc.org/)?

I tried this:

```
%w(one two three).each do |type|
  # The #{type} way
  # @return [String] the #{type} way
  define_method("#{type}_way") do ... end
end
```

But, unfortunately, not working.

Comment: Describe what "not working" means. You get no output? You get output but it's not formatted? It's formatted but it's not the format you want?

Comment: Nothing appears : no methods and no docs for these methods

Comment: You can't document a dynamically created method, it has to be statically defined. Yard would have to run your code then use introspection to generate the methods available at run time, which is not practical.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you move the method creation into a class method, you could use a macro:

```
class Foo

  # @!macro [attach] generate
  #   @method $1_way
  #   The $1 way
  #   @return [String] the $1 way
  def self.generate(type)
    define_method("#{type}_way") do
    end
  end

  generate :one
  generate :two
  generate :three

end
```

YARD Output:

> ```
> - (String) one_way
> ```
>
> The one way
>
> **Returns:**
>
> (`String`) — the one way
>
> ---
>
> ```
> - (String) three_way
> ```
>
> The three way
>
> **Returns:**
>
> (`String`) — the three way
>
> ---
>
> ```
> - (String) two_way
> ```
>
> The two way
>
> **Returns:**
>
> (`String`) — the two way

Comment: why doesn't it work in a loop? `[:one,:two,:three].each {|n| generate(n)}`. does it?

Comment: OK @Stefan but.. in cases like this, do we really have to adapt code in order to use YARD? I mean maybe less readable code in favor of auto doc production ... or is there some other way to document methods that are dynamically defined?

Comment: @masciugo I guess this is the way YARD works. Besides, I think method definition inside a loop is less readable, but YMMV.